# Where is the constructor of Model in ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, constructor

I am working on ASP.NET Core MVC Application that uses Entity framework Core. So everything seemed ok but somehow i came up with an interesting question and couldn't find the answer in the web.
Here what i know. 
When we use EF Core it gives us ability to represent database tables as classes and to work with them. I have a CONTEXT.cs class that creates entities, gives them properties corresponding to database.
Here is my question
If a model is a class then where is the constructor? Or that is done when i "create" something and the whole info comes to controller like this( [Bind("id", "name") ]Materials materials) and data is simply being added to context

Thanks in advance. Please correct me if i'm writing anything wrong

Comment: where is the constructor?  wherever you create it.  YOU create the model. thus YOU create any constructor that you need.  it’s important to note that prior to ef core 2.1 you could only use parameterless constructors

Answer (score 0):

I think that this link will answer the first part of your question:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

And about binding models which coming from controller actions. At least in previous versions, the data was set through public field setters that can implement complex logic. For example, a boolean setter can actually add a value to a private List when assigning a 'true' value.